# Connection to SQS refused

Tags: amazon-sqs

I am developing a service which reads messages from SQS, does some processing and posts the result to a different service.

When I initially developed this, the service was working perfectly fine, however after some days (about 5 days) I got this exception:

```
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection to https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com refused { org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:280)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:165)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:869)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.getQueueAttributes(AmazonSQSClient.java:453)
```

I reactivated the service and it started working again. My question is has someone faced this issue? If so what is the best way to handle such exception?

Other interesting fact is the same exception happened on all the hosts of the service at nearly the same time. Can this be because of an SQS outage or are such transient connection failures expected?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, before posting a question.

Comment: As a short term fix, could you perhaps write a script to periodically reactivate the service?  You wouldn't have to manually restart it until you find the right answer.

Comment: @UnniKris: Will do from next time, new to SO :)

Comment: @Prime This doesn't seem to be a viable solution. This would mask the actual problem. I can also handle the exception, log and ignore it - have a log watcher which can alarm if such failures happen, that would let my service run without needing a re-start.
What I am looking for here is the root cause for this exception, is this expected? If so how frequently. If this is transient, after how many retry failures should I alarm?

Comment: @goldberg i definitely wasn't proposing this as a long term solution, just as an ad hoc measure if this question took a couple days to be worked out.  Your log idea sounds better anyways.